# how could set multi separator of "_.truncate" of Lodash?

Tags: javascript, lodash

how can I separate by "," or "-" or " " ?

```js
    let _r = _.truncate('hi-diddly-ho there, neighborino', {
          'length': 16,
          'separator': /,- +/
        });
        console.log(_r);   //need output: hi
    
    let _r = _.truncate('hi!diddly ho there, neighborino', {
          'length': 16,
          'separator': /,- +/
        });
        console.log(_r);   //need output: hi!diddly
    
    let _r = _.truncate('hi!diddly!ho,there, neighborino', {
          'length': 16,
          'separator': /,- +/
        });
        console.log(_r);   //need output: hi!diddly!ho
```

if setting `"/,- +/"` is not working, what should I do?

Comment: Thats the example? What is your expected output?

Comment: i added the example code, thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regular expression is basically saying, "match `,-` followed by at least one space".

<sup>[Check it on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/SGMjLy/1)</sup>

This would match `",-   "`, for example.

What you want is a character group of `,`, `-` and space (note that you need to escape `-` there):

```
/[,\- ]/
```

<sup>[Check it on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/alKajx/1)</sup>

Comment: thank you ! we could get the right result from "test my testing string" and "test, my, testing, string", but still wrong from "", our testing code is : { console.log('testing.....................', _.truncate('test- my-testing-string', {'length':20, 'separator': /[, \-]+/})); }

Comment: What is the output, and what's the desired output?

Comment: all the desired output is "test" only :)

Comment: @user1556299 But `_.truncate` works by cutting the string as late as possible so that its length is less than or equal to the length you specify. 20 characters are `test- my-testing-str`, so it's cut at the `-` before, returning `test- my-testing...`. Why do you expect a different behaviour?

Comment: yeah, i wanna get the shortest string as the result, if there's no "," or "-" or " ", the shortest result is the first 20 characters, Otherwise the shortest should be the characters before the "," or "-" or " ".

Comment: @user1556299 Well, then `_.truncate` is not what you need here.

Comment: Got it, Thank you :)